# Display window in the langton ant in c++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0, mat

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include<string>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    class Ant
    {
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        int orientation;
    };

    class World
    {
    public:
    Ant c;      /*c is data member to class World and Ant is 
                           itself a class*/

        Mat* board;     //Board is a pointer to Mat
        World(int rows, int columns, int x, int y, int orientation);

    public:
        void further_steps();
    };
    World::World(int rows, int columns, int x, int y, int orientation)
    {
    this->board = new Mat(rows, columns, CV_8U);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                this->board->at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
            }
        }

        this->c.x = x;
        this->c.y = y;
        this->c.orientation = orientation;
    }

    void World::further_steps()
    {
        int rows = board->rows;
        int cols=board->cols;
        int x = c.x;
        int y = c.y;
        if (board->at<uchar>(rows, cols) = 255)
        {
            board->at<uchar>(rows / 2, cols / 2) = 0;

        }
        else if (board->at<uchar>(rows, cols) = 0)
        {
            c.x = 255;
            c.y = 255;
        }

    }
int main()
    {
        //World W(100, 100, 50, 50, 0);
        int rows, cols, x, y, orientation;
        cout << "enter no of rows" << endl;
        cin >> rows;
        cout << "enter no of cols" << endl;
        cin >> cols;
        cout << "enter the X co-ordinate of c" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "enter the  Y co-ordinate of c" << endl;
        cin >> y;
        cout << "enter the orientation of the c" << endl;
        cin >> orientation;
        World W(rows, cols, x, y, orientation);
        W.further_steps();
        Mat *board;
        namedWindow("langton's_Ant", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);  
        imshow("langton's_Ant", *board);
        return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to access x and y by c.at(x,y). But in vishual c++,its giving me an error as the c is not of matrix or mat data type.

let me know how do I access the (x,y) coordinate or pixel of the mat. So I could access my ant via these coordinates. Also there is an exception runtime error while running the code. so please help me to remove it.